# integer(0) zero-length output as index for data.frame

Tags: r

Let's say I have

```
M <- data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4)
```

Now I check elements of M by which() and I got an empty result

```
uniqueElements <- apply(M,1,function(x){length(unique(x)})
delete <- which(uniqueElements == 1)
```

I want to delete rows of M which fulfilled my condition = NO deletion

```
M[-delete,]
```

How to proceed?

Comment: 'delete' will not exist outside that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowSums`

```
 M[rowSums(M)!=5,]
```

If you are using `apply`, then use logical index instead of numeric index

```
 M[!apply(M, 1, sum)==5,]
```

as in the example, there is not a single row that satisfies the condition

```
  apply(M, 1, sum)==5
  #[1] FALSE FALSE
```

So, `which` will give

```
  which(apply(M, 1, sum)==5)
  #integer(0)
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding... I know that my condition results NO subsettable row (zero-length). I need to get original M, not empty data.frame.

Comment: @MartinHroch `M[rowSums(M)!=5,]` returns the whole dataset based on your example.